# Why CVS to GIT migration files having difference after migration?

Tags: cvs2git, cvsimport

I am migrating CVS repository to GIT using cvs2git tool but am getting minor changes on few files after CVS to GIT migration. Is this ok ? **OR** should I need to migrate properly?

```
  [root@test myproject-cvs2git]# git diff  -w resource/config/test.policy /testcvs/common/resource/config/test.policy
diff --git a/resource/config/test.policy b/testcvs/common/resource/config/test.policy
index 36fbf3a..c402a95 100755
--- a/resource/config/test.policy
+++ b/testcvs/myproject/resource/config/test.policy
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@
 //
 // * Read access to the document root directory
 //
-// $Id$
+// $Id: test.policy,v 1.1.1.1 2011/06/01 11:25:59 User Exp $
 // ============================================================================
```

Comment: What types of differences exactly? Is there any pattern to which files the differences occur in? Do they persist if you e.g. do `git diff -w`?

Comment: @underscore_d Updated my question with git diff -w

Comment: Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with CVS `keyword expansion`. Learn about `keyword expansion`. Git doesn't do it. (Some may say that git supports it in a limited way, but that's being very generous. It basically doesn't.)

See this answer [cvs2svn changes 'date' string in source codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199649/cvs2svn-changes-date-string-in-source-codes)

cvs2git uses cvs2svn as a first step.